# bind and dns master and slave

Tags: domain-name-system, bind

After going through OReilly dns and bind book, I still have problems with a master and slave configuration, I am getting

`client 192.168.1.67#34245: update '<domain>.co.uk/IN' denied`
as a syslog error for the master definintion of the zone.
and
`named[19034]: client 192.168.1.67#47452: update forwarding '<domain>.co.uk/IN' denied`
 as a syslog error for the slave definition

The server that has the master zones has a named.conf :

```
options {
    allow-transfer { 192.168.1/24; };
}
// The reverse lookup of 192.168.1.* - the local IP addresses
zone "1.168.192.in-addr.arpa" in {
    type master;
    file "192.168.1.db";
    allow-transfer { key TRANSFER; };
    allow-update { key TRANSER; };
};

// The forward lookup of hosts on this domain
zone "<domain>.co.uk" in {
    type master;
    file "<domain>.co.uk.db";
    allow-transfer { key TRANSFER; };
    allow-update { key TRANSER; };
};

key "TRANSFER" {
    algorithm hmac-md5;
    secret "<the secret key>";
};

# Slave DNS server
server 192.167.1.67 {
    keys {
            TRANSFER;
    };
};
```

The server that has the slave zones has :

```
options {
    allow-transfer { none; };
}

// The reverse lookup of 192.168.1.* - the local IP addresses
zone "1.168.192.in-addr.arpa" in {
    type slave;
    file "bak.192.168.1.db";
    masters { 192.168.1.52 key TRANSFER; };
    allow-update-forwarding { any; };
};

// The forward lookup of hosts on this domain
zone "blairsltd.co.uk" in {
    type slave;
    file "bak.blairsltd.co.uk.db";
    masters { 192.168.1.52 key TRANSFER; };
};

key "TRANSFER" {
    algorithm hmac-md5;
    secret "<the same secret key>";
};

# Master DNS server
server 192.167.1.52 {
    keys {
            TRANSFER;
    };
};
```

I think eveything is configured so it will allow all legitimate updates securely from the slave to the master, what am I missing?

Comment: do you need to allow AXFR transfers for the slave ip?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

`allow-update-forwarding { any; };` is only on the slave's reverse lookup zone, so it's gonna block attempts to update the forward lookup zone on it - that's the error message on the slave.

The master is configured to require updates to be signed with the transfer key - based on its error message, that's probably not happening since the intent seems to have been to use that key for transfers, correct?

Comment: O.K. I have added `allow-update-forwarding { key TRANSFER; };` to both slave zones, and fixed the I.P. address typo but I am still getting the above error on the master.

Comment: @Tim You still have `allow-update { key TRANSER; };`, which is preventing unsigned updates.  If your intent is to allow unauthenticated updates, then change to `{ all; };`; if you don't need unsigned dynamic updates, or even dynamic updates at all, leave this in place.

Comment: Why do I need to allow unsigned updates, I thought I had done everything to allow secure updates?  What other updates are trying to be applied?

Comment: @Tim Updates are failing because clients are sending unsigned updates.  If you don't want to allow unsigned updates, then just ignore the error messages when they fail.

Comment: Is there anyway to tell which clients are responsible for this, I'd like all updates to be done and all to be secure?

Answer (score 2):

Looks like some of your IPs are incorrect. Unless you have some special private network, change this:

```
# Slave DNS server
server 192.167.1.67 {
    keys {
            TRANSFER;
    };
};

# Master DNS server
server 192.167.1.52 {
    keys {
            TRANSFER;
    };
};
```

to this:

```
# Slave DNS server
server 192.168.1.67 {
    keys {
            TRANSFER;
    };
};

# Master DNS server
server 192.168.1.52 {
    keys {
            TRANSFER;
    };
};
```

Comment: I can't believe I made that typo!